# backbone - trying to rerender a view with the next or previous model in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to get into backbone and have the following which is an attempt at doing an image gallery. I am trying to use render with a model in a collection. I will show the first element of the collection but I would like to add support for simply rerendering with the next element but I don't know how to do this .

I have implemented next and previous on my model like the following:

```
arc.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
    next: function () {
        if (this.collection) {
            return this.collection.at(this.collection.indexOf(this) + 1);
        }
    },previous: function () {
        if (this.collection) {
            return this.collection.at(this.collection.indexOf(this) - 1);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem here (there could be more than the one I am asking about though) is in the loadNext method. How would I get the current location in this collection and to increment it?

```
arc.ItemsGalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: $('#mig-container'),
    events: {'click .next-btn' : 'loadNext', 
             'click .previous-btn':'loadPrevious' },
       template:_.template($('#mig-image-tmp').text()),
      initialize: function() {
          _.bindAll( this, 'render' );
          // render the initial state
          var thisModel=this.collection.first();
          this.render(thisModel);
      },

      render: function(xModel) {  // <- is it ok to do it this way?
          var compiled=this.template(xModel.toJSON());
          this.$el.html(compiled);
          return this;
      },

      loadNext: function(){
        console.log('i want to load Next');
        this.render(this.collection.next());  // <- how would I do this
        this.render(this.collection.first().next());  // <- this works by always giving me the second.
        // I need to replace first with current

      },
      loadPrevious: function(){
        console.log('i want to load Previous');
      }
```

Or is there a better way to implement this?

thx in advance

**edit #1**

```
 arc.ItemsGalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#mig-container'),
        events: {'click .next-btn' : 'loadNext', 'click .previous-btn':'loadPrevious' },
         template:_.template($('#mig-image-tmp').text()),
        initialize: function() {
          _.bindAll( this, 'render' );
          this.render(this.collection.first());  // <- this works correct
        },

        render: function(xModel) {
          console.log(xModel.toJSON());
          var compiled=this.template(xModel.toJSON());
          this.$el.html(compiled);
          return this;
        },
        loadNext: function(){
          console.log('i want to load next');
          this.render(this.collection.next());   // <- this doesn't seem to do anything, event is called correctly but doesn't seem to move to next element
        },

    However if I adjust to this, it will load the 3rd element of the array

loadNext: function(){
  console.log('i want to load Previous');
  this.render(this.collection.at(2));
},
```

How would I use this.collection.next() to get this behavior?

thx

Comment: Again, why isn't `'click .prev-btn'` in your `events`?

Comment: sorry mu, just starting with backbone - the tutorials aren't great. can an events hash hold multiple events?

Comment: Sure, `events` can hold as many unique event specs as you need: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2TAgW/ The `events` are just used to build a bunch of the delegate forms of jQuery's `on` after all.

Comment: thx @muistooshort - I've updated the question. I'm still having a bit of a trouble with dealing with the current index in the collection. I am sure there is some simple reason but didn't see anything in the Backbone / underscore docs that jumped out at me. Again, just trying to get the hang of it but did search. appreciate any help.

Comment: the easiest way is that create new variable to keep model index, set value inside initialize, by the way you can call collection.at()

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like you're looking for is a way to use the `Collection` to manipulate the next/prev stuff. What you currently have only puts it on the model. Here's a base `Collection` I use in my projects:

```
App.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  constructor: function(models, options) {
    var self = this;
    var oldInitialize = this.initialize;
    this.initialize = function() {
      self.on('reset', self.onReset);
      oldInitialize.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    Backbone.Collection.call(this, models, options);
  },
  onReset: function() {
    this.setActive(this.first());
  },
  setActive: function(active, options) {
    var cid = active;
    if ( active instanceof Backbone.Model ) {
      cid = active.cid;
    }
    this.each(function(model) {
      model.set('current', model.cid === cid, options);
    });
  },
  getActive: function() {
    return this.find(function(model) {
      return model.get('current');
    });
  },
  next: function() {
    return this.at(this.indexOf(this.getActive()) + 1);
  },
  prev: function() {
    return this.at(this.indexOf(this.getActive()) - 1);
  }
});
```

It's probably not perfect, but it works for me. Hopefully it can at least put you on the right track. Here is how I use it:

```
var someOtherCollection = App.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel
});
```

Comment: thx, I've tried getting this to work but no dice. It looks like it should work but it's not. I've included the code above in edit #1.I can call `this.collection.at(2)1 which does rerender the view with a new model. I know I'm doing something really boneheadish.

Answer (score 1):

kalley's answer is right on, but I will throw in another example.

I would entertain the idea of keeping the current model inside of `state` model, and work from there. You can store other application information within the `state` model as well.

Your model declaration would look like the following. Notice I renamed `previous` to `prev`. `Backbone.Model` already has a `previous` method and we don't want to over-ride it.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  index:function() {
    return this.collection.indexOf(this);
  },
  next:function() {
    return this.collection.at(this.index()+1) || this;
  },
  prev:function() {
    return this.collection.at(this.index()-1) || this;
  }
});
```

Have a generic `Backbone.Model` that holds your selected model:

```
var state = new Backbone.Model();
```

In the view you will listen for changes to the state model and render accordingly:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#mig-container'
  template:_.template($('#mig-image-tmp').html()),
  events: {
    'click .prev' : 'prev',
    'click .next' : 'next'
  },
  initialize:function() {
    this.listenTo(state,'change:selected',this.render);
    state.set({selected:this.collection.at(0)});
  },
  render:function() {
    var model = state.get('selected');
    this.$el.html(this.template(model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },
  next:function() {
    // get the current model
    var model = state.get('selected');

    /* Set state with the next model, fires a change event and triggers render.
       Unless you are at the last model, then no event will fire.
     */
    state.set({selected:model.next()});
  },
  prev:function() {
    var model = state.get('selected');
    state.set({selected:model.prev()});
  }
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/OlaRAVe/1/edit). I like the `state` model approach because I'm not storing application-state information within my models.

If you don't like the `state` model approach, you can always just throw it on the floor:

```
/ .. code above ../

initialize:function() {
  this.model = this.collection.at(0);
  this.render();
},
render:function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  return this;
},
next:function() {
  this.model = this.model.nxt();
  this.render();
},
prev:function() {
  this.model = this.model.prev();
  this.render();
}
```

Comment: @timpone, Did you notice the demo? http://jsbin.com/OlaRAVe/2/edit. Click `run with js` to get it going.