# having problems with simple backbone app loading a collection and then dynamically iterating through it

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to pick up backbone and would like to do a simple image gallery app but am having problems.

I'd like to instantiate my view with a collection of items (named itemsArray) and then load the first model of that collection into a view. This view will provide a previous and next button and I've set up the events.

I'm confused about how to pass this collection into a Backbone view and tell it to load the first element. Also, manipulating the collection with prev / next doesn't seem to be working correctly. I asked this question before ([backbone - trying to rerender a view with the next or previous model in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478156/backbone-trying-to-rerender-a-view-with-the-next-or-previous-model-in-a-collec)) but think it's better if I post the whole fragment here. I have seen sample code similar to this in tutorials but I think the loading of the single model with knowledge of the collection has proven problematic. I have provided the full source code below:

```
<div id='item-container'></div>
<script type='text/template' id='tmp'>
  <%=header %>
  <img src='<%=assets[0].url %>' />
  <div class='next-btn'>next</div> <div class='prev-btn'>prev</div>
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

      var arc={};
      // 2. items to be made into an Items collection
      var itemsArray=[{'id':4, 'header':'my header','detail':'my detail', 'price':'$12.25', assets:[{'url':'/tmp-images/surf.jpg'}]},
          {'id':7, 'header':'my header 2','detail':'my detail 2', 'price':'$14.25', assets:[{'url':'/tmp-images/jamaica.jpg'}]},
          {'id':11, 'header':'my header 3','detail':'my detail 3', 'price':'$21.00',assets:[{'url':'/tmp-images/jamaica-2.jpg'}]}
      ];

      // 3. item class 
      arc.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});
      // 4. items collection made up of item
      arc.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:arc.Item
      });

      var items = new arc.Items(itemsArray);

      //console.log(menu_items);

      arc.ItemsGalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#item-container'),
            events: {'click .next-btn' : 'loadNext', 'click .prev-btn':'loadPrevious' },
             template:_.template($('#tmp').text()),
            initialize: function() {
              _.bindAll( this, 'render' );
              // 5. this is definitely wrong, trying to render template with single instance of model
              //  seems like I should be doing something like this.collection.at(0) or something but that isn't working
              //this.render(this.model);


             /* 6.  works but not an array
             this.render({header:'my name',assets:[
                    {url:'/image/some.jpg'}
              ]});
              */
              // 7. not working header is not defined
              this.render(this.collection.at(0));  // error 'header is not defined'
              console.log(this.collection.at(0));  // in console this kinda looks like a model but do I need to call another method on it?
            },

            render: function(xModel) {
              var compiled=this.template(xModel);
              this.$el.html(compiled);
              return this;
            },
            loadNext: function(){
               // 8. not sure what to do here
            },
            loadPrevious: function(){
              console.log('i want to load Previous');
              // 9. not working
              this.render(this.collection.prev());

            }

        });

      var itemView=new arc.ItemsGalleryView({ collection: items });
    });
    </script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. How would I pass a collection? and then manipulate where I am in the collection via events?

thx

[image]

Comment: I've added a screenshot for the error above. Honestly, I was just trying to get it to work and assigning it to this.model wasn't working either. Not sure if this is an issue with using collection in the options object when creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing a model to a template, note that every attribute is held in a special hash. For you, it'd be `model.attributes.header`. (so `<%= attributes.header %>`)

It is usually suggested you pass your model attributes directly to your templates though: `this.render(this.collection.at(0).toJSON());` (and that'll work with your current template)

Comment: thx, that part works. any idea on how to implement the next and previous? appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you usually do not pass arguments to `render()`. You're also not actually appending your `#tmpl` template to your `#item-container`.

I have [created a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juco/Ju7S6/) with your code. I've demonstrated creating a separate view for your collection and model, as I feel this was confusing things.

Comment: thx juco, so this is closer but what I'm really trying to do is to render just the first element and not all 3 at once and have the user navigate via forward or next. I tried tweaking your code but to no avail.